# Getting libssl abd libcrypto conflict warning while compiling php on RHEL 7.8

Tags: php, ssl, redhat, compilation, warning

I m getting following warning messages while compiling php on RHEL7.8
I am able to successfully compile and install php but I am not sure what will be the side effect of these warnings.
Is there any way to resolve these warning?

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by //usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1


#OpenSSL Installation

./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl shared
make
make test
make install


#Apache Installation

./configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/apache2 \
--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl \
--with-included-apr \
--with-mpm=prefork \
--enable-ssl \
--enable-modules=all \
--enable-mods-shared=most \
make
make install

#PHP Installation

'./configure' \
'--prefix=/usr/local/php7' \
'--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' \
'--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php7/conf' \
'--with-curl' \
'--with-kerberos' \
'--with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl' \
'--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl' \
'--with-zlib' \
'--with-zlib-dir=/lib64/' \
'--enable-bcmath' \
'--enable-ftp' \
'--enable-gd-native-ttf' \
'--enable-mbstring' \
'--enable-opcache' \
'--enable-pcntl' \
'--enable-pdo' \
'--enable-shared' \
'--enable-shmop' \
'--enable-soap' \
'--enable-sockets' \
'--enable-sysvshm' \
'--enable-xml' \
'--enable-zip' \
'--without-libzip' \
```

## ldd /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff46493000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fc710c31000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fc710746000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc710542000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc710326000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc70ff58000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc710ec3000)
```

## ldd /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcea29e000)
libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fcb03f33000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/local/apache2/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007fcb03d09000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fcb03adf000)
libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/local/apache2/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007fcb038a4000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fcb0369f000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fcb03497000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fcb03260000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcb03044000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcb02e40000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcb02a72000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcb04195000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fcb0286f000)
```

## ldd /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc2019d000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fb63e115000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fb63dc2a000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fb63da25000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb63d81d000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fb63d5e6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb63d3ca000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb63d1c6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb63cdf8000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb63e5e4000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fb63cbf5000)

# ldd /usr/local/php7/bin/php

/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffadb8d3000)
        libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007ffad4ed8000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007ffad7d23000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007ffad45dc000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007ffad91a8000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ffadb69c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffad742c000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007ffad7ab9000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffada34d000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007ffad7229000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ffad77fa000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007ffad8443000)
        libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x00007ffad67a0000)
        libifasf.so => /home/informix/lib/libifasf.so (0x00007ffadac28000)
        libifcli.so => /home/informix/lib/cli/libifcli.so (0x00007ffadb2e3000)
        libifdmr.so => /home/informix/lib/cli/libifdmr.so (0x00007ffadb0db000)
        libifgen.so => /home/informix/lib/esql/libifgen.so (0x00007ffada9c6000)
        libifgls.so => /home/informix/lib/esql/libifgls.so (0x00007ffada551000)
        libifglx.so => /home/informix/lib/esql/libifglx.so (0x00007ffada14b000)
        libifos.so => /home/informix/lib/esql/libifos.so (0x00007ffada7a4000)
        libifsql.so => /home/informix/lib/esql/libifsql.so (0x00007ffadae87000)
        libjpeg.so.62 => /lib64/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007ffad9693000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007ffad7f27000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007ffad69d3000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007ffad815a000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007ffad6bd7000)
        liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ffad533d000)
        libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ffad50e8000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ffad6de7000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffad8c14000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007ffad89fa000)
        libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007ffad554c000)
        libnss3.so => /lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007ffad5dc3000)
        libnssutil3.so => /lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007ffad5b93000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007ffad415d000)
        libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007ffad578a000)
        libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007ffad598f000)
    libpng15.so.15 => /lib64/libpng15.so.15 (0x00007ffad98e8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffad700d000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ffad9d1b000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007ffad9b13000)
        libsasl2.so.3 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007ffad43bf000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007ffad4cb1000)
        libsmime3.so => /lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007ffad60f2000)
        libssh2.so.1 => /lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007ffad6573000)
        libssl3.so => /lib64/libssl3.so (0x00007ffad631a000)
        libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007ffad4a3f000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007ffad8f16000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007ffad8690000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007ffad9f35000)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe9bb3000)
```

Comment: Why would you need to compile your own PHP? Use packages. [Compilation can go wrong](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/where-compilation-went-wrong) in many ways and certainly, is not something that should be lightly considered on RHEL machines (you're essentially giving up on SELinux and security updates which are delivered through packaging).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these warnings, because you try to link PHP against OpenSSL 1.1.x (`*.so.1.1`) while libssh2 is linked against OpenSSL 1.0.x (`*.so.10`).

The only way to really resolve this is to link both, PHP and libssh2, against the same version of OpenSSL (or you could try to figure out whether you need the component that brings in libssh2 and avoid building this PHP extension – but that could be cURL…and thus this suggestion might simply not work then).

According to the [README of libssh2](https://github.com/badoo/libssh2/blob/master/README), it also could be an option to rebuild libssh2 yourself either without OpenSSL support at all, or with libgcrypt support. But before doing this, you should cross-check whether you use libssh2 at other places and which impact such a change causes there.

Practically, this OpenSSL linking mixture *normally* still works fine, even it throws build-time warnings…but there is no guarantee though. If it raises problems in this case, I would expect them, aside of a segmentation fault or a otherwise crash when loading mod_php or starting php-fpm, to anything encryption related.